# Boostrap template scalling image slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It's this template
https://startbootstrap.com/template/modern-business

When resizing browser smaller or on mobile device images of the slider get cropped(left/right) and text bellow disappears. Any idea how to scale it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the `.carousel-item` elements is set to be `height: 65vh` or `min-height: 300px`, whichever is greater. So when you start narrowing the display, the aspect ratio of the image will start breaking, as there is not much variation on the viewport's height, which is the determining factor.

To respect aspect-ratio on smaller devices, you should add a max-height property and set it to `56.25vw` (100 times 9 divided 16, given that the width of the image will always be 100 of viewport's width), this way ensuring you'll always get a 16:9 aspect-ratio (assuming that the site, like the template, will always use 1920x1080 images).

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 65vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 56.25vw;
    /* other stuff... */
}
```

This way you'll ensure aspect-ratio is respected on smaller screens, while you avoid respecting it on larger displays, where keeping the image at its aspect-ratio would cause it to overflow to the bottom of the screen.

We still have the `min-height` attribute, that will always be preferred by the browser before `max-height`, so on very small screens it will still adjust our height to 300px. We can avoid that simply by removing it:

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 65vh;
    max-height: 56.25vw;
    /* other stuff... */
}
```

If we'd want to force the aspect-ratio on all screens, we should remove the `max-height` property and set our `height` property to `56.25vw`:

```css
.carousel-item {
    height: 56.25vw;
    /* other stuff... */
}
```

Regarding the text, if we want it to show on smaller screens we must remove the display classes () from the `div.carousel-caption` element:

```html
<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Second Slide</h3>
    <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It solved 30%. It scales right on phone, but I just found out it also previously cropped (top/bottom). And the text is still invisible on phone view. Think the best solution is to replace the whole slider with new one.

Comment: @dnkn if you want it to respect aspect-ratio even in the smallest of screens, just remove the `min-height` attribute

Comment: @dnkn just edited the answer explaining that, it should now cover all screen sizes

Comment: @dnkn and yes, top and bottom are cropped on larger versions... if you want to always have a 16:9 aspect-ratio, you can just remove `min-` and `max-` height completely, and set `height: 56.25vw;`. That way you'll always have a 16:9 image displayed fully in your screen.

Comment: @dnkn in order to show the text, you must change the classes of the `.carousel-caption` div, I just updated the answer accordingly... please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Ok, I've tested on both pc and mobile, now it scales right (with only height: 56.25vw;).
To make text appear I removed 'd-none d-md-block' from '<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">' in index.html.

Comment: @dnkn great, if the answer was helpful please accept it and/or upvote it

Comment: How/where to accept/upvote? Can't see options.

Comment: @dnkn at the beginning of my answer you'll see a number 0 with arrows above and below it, and a checkmark... to upvote click the upward arrow, to accept click the checkmark. Image: https://postimg.cc/sMMKrmST